# Retrieving post data from database not showing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I try to retrieve data from the database, fixed error messages but still data isn't showing up, http://localhost/webpage/info.php?post_id=76 (post id depends on the post that i click). Also, I am aware that some variables aren't showing, I am working on putting everything in place just the things that I placed don't show up. Also there is a connection to a database, only that I won't show whole file because its too big.

Code of the function that gives problems [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joetv.png):

```
function single_post(){

    if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
        global $con;
        $get_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        $get_posts = "select * from posts where post_id='get_id'";
        $run_posts = mysqli_query($con, $get_posts);
        $row_posts = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts);

        $post_id = $row_posts['post_id'];
        $user_id = $row_posts['user_id'];
        $post_content = $row_posts['post_content'];
        $post_content2 = $row_posts['post_content2'];
        $price = $row_posts['price'];
        $pclass = $row_posts['pclass'];
        $specificclass = $row_posts['specificclass'];
        $upload_image = $row_posts['upload_image'];
        $post_date = $row_posts['post_date'];

        $user = "select * from users where user_id='$user_id' AND posts='yes'";

        $run_user = mysqli_query($con , $user);
        $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

        $user_name = $row_user['user_name'];
        $user_image = $row_user['user_image'];

        if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
            $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        }
        $get_posts = "select post_id from users where post_id='$post_id'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con,$get_posts);

        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        $post = $_GET['post_id'];
        $get_user = "select * from posts where post_id='$post'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

        $p_id = $row['post_id'];

        if ($p_id != $post_id) {
            echo "<script>alert('ERROR')</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo"
            <h2><strong>Información del producto:</strong></h2><br>
            <p><strong>Nombre del producto: </strong>$post_content</p><br>
            <p><strong>Información: </strong>$post_content2</p><br>
            <p><strong>Precio dispuesto a pagar: </strong> $price</p><br>
            <p><strong>Categoría: </strong> $pclass</p><br>
            <p><strong>Subcategoría: </strong> $specificclass</p><br>
            ";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting as a typo; you left out the `$` in `where post_id='get_id'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is typo mistake in code for get_id.

```
  $get_posts = "select * from posts where post_id='get_id'";
```

should be

```
  $get_posts = "select * from posts where post_id='$get_id'";
```

and regarding security, please sanitize your $_GET value...

if it is always in number format, use

```
 is_numeric
```

to check it....

for example..

```
 if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
   $get_id = sanitized($_GET['post_id']); // sanitize with your created code for it....
   if(is_numeric($get_id)){
    global $con;
      // $get_id = $_GET['post_id']; no need of it as we havev declared it above
    $get_posts = "select * from posts where post_id='$get_id'";
       //..... rest code.....




  }else{

 // show error regarding get id.. like not found etc..

  }
```